# If $f$ is a Schwartz function, then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

> Let $\mathcal S$ be the Schwartz space on $\mathbb R$, i.e., the set of functions $f\in\cal C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb R$ such that for every $k,l\ge 0$
> $$
> \sup |x|^k|f^{(l)}(x)|<\infty.
> $$
> If $f\in\cal S$, then
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx.
> $$

I don't know how to use this rapid decay of $x^kf^{(l)}$ property to show this. If I use the change of variable $u=-x$ I seem to get that the sides are opposite. Why this isn't correct?

Any help you'll be appreciated.

Comment: $\int_a^b f(-x)dx = \int_{-b}^{-a} f(y)dy$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is an even function then $f(-x)=f(x)$ so the equation holds. If $f$ is odd then both sides are $0$. In general, $f=g+h$  with $g$ odd and $h$ even.